# Configure embedded dns server of docker for custom SRV records via docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dns

Is it possible to set custom `A` and `SRV` records in the embedded dns server of docker via the `docker-compose.yml`? I want to set the following

```
     myhost.mysuffix.local IN A 114.123.456.789
     myservice.mysuffix.local IN SRV 0 5 8009 myhost.mysuffix.local
```